# Add and delete table rows dynamically on button click

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am creating a form which adds a table row on a button click so far its working fine but I want to have a delete button beside every row generated by the button click, but not on the first row. I've searched many blogs but came up with nothing can anyone guide me in doing it? I am just a beginner.
Here is my script:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var i=1;
function addRow()
{
          var tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
          var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
          var iteration = lastRow - 1;
          var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

          var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
          var el = document.createElement('input');
          el.type = 'text';
          el.name = 'name' + i;
          el.id = 'name' + i;
          el.size = 20;
          el.maxlength = 20;
          firstCell.appendChild(el);

          var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
          var el2 = document.createElement('input');
          el2.type = 'text';
          el2.name = 'address' + i;
          el2.id = 'address' + i;
          el2.size = 20;
          el2.maxlength = 20;
          secondCell.appendChild(el2);

          var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2);
          var el3 = document.createElement('input');
          el3.type = 'text';
          el3.name = 'contactNum' + i;
          el3.id = 'contactNum' + i;
          el3.size = 20;
          el3.maxlength = 20;
          thirdCell.appendChild(el3);
         frm.h.value=i;
                  i++;


}
</script>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title></head>

<body>
<form action="submit.php" method="post" name="frm" id="frm">
<table width="40%" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Address</strong> </td>
    <td><strong>Contact Num</strong> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="20" maxlength="20" /></td>
    <td><input name="address" type="text" id="address" size="20" maxlength="20" /></td>
    <td><input name="contactNum" type="text" id="contactNum" size="20" maxlength="12" /></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow();" />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<label>
<input name="h" type="hidden" id="h" value="0" />
</label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://youhack.me/2010/03/26/remove-data-in-a-div-after-successfully-deleted-using-jquery/
Is this kind of what you're going for? Or something similar to it

Comment: yes i need that but the delete button should generate with the second row if u run my script there will be a first row i want to generate deletebutton wen a new row is generated

Comment: Dunno why, but even that isn't working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cpPZr/).

Comment: thank u brandon but can u modify my code acutally i new to this so dont have much idea pls would be a huge favour

Comment: that script is working on my end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [add row](http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/table.addrow.php) jquery plugin.

Comment: thanks sir but since i am just a beginner can u help me modify my code pls

Comment: yah sure what is it..?? don't call me sir..?? i m here because once i was at your stage...its may be starting for u..but its okay keep it up.

Comment: well thank u but can u just modify my code so that i can use it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [deleteRow() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp) with the [rowIndex property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tablerow_rowindex.asp). Try using an onClick(this) call for the button in the row.

Answer (score 0):

Better try to search for data tables.. They can be used directly. You need not code in more also.. You also have many other features embedded in it.

Comment: my need is not datatable sir